# Fundamental Thm of Calc part 1 with part 2?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

If I have a problem $$g(x)=\int_2^x \ln(t) \ dt$$

Wouldn't $g'(x)$ be just $\ln(x)$? Then when it is asking me to solve this using part 2, not part 1, how would I evaluate this when my upper bound is not a constant?

I would say $\ln(x) - x - (\ln(2)-2)$ but that is wrong. Please, explain in plain example and words what I am missing about the fundamental theorem of calculus to be able to solve this problem.

Comment: I don't think there's a standard on which part of the Fundamental Theorem is the first and which is the second, and even if there is you should still say which is which. Also I am completely lost about what the question is here. What do you mean "solve this"? What is "this"? Is it to evaluate $g(x)$? or compute $g'(x)$? Something else?

Comment: To compute $g'(x)$ which is $\ln(x)$

Comment: If the integrand is continuous then both parts of fundamental theorem of calculus are equivalent. And in your case it is utterly pointless to find the integral and then differentiate it, when you know that your integrand is the final answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\;F(t)\;$ be a primitive function for $\;\log t\;$ (in fact, $\;F(t)=t\log t-t+C\;$, though this is unimportant in this case...), then using the FTC:

$$g(x)=\int_2^x\log t\,dt=F(x)-F(2)\implies g'(x)=\left(F(x)-F(2)\right)'=F'(x)=\log x$$

Comment: in this we are saying $\log x = \ln x$?

Comment: @Computer Yes, indeed. It is a habit in higher mathematics to denote the natural logarithm by $\;\log x\;$ instead of by $\;\ln x\;$ ...

Comment: Why is it that $F(x) - F(2) = \ln2$. Basically I interpret this as having used only the part 1 and no part 2 at all?

Comment: @Computer I didn't write that: that is false. What I wrote is that **the derivative** of $\;(F(x)-F(2))\;$ is, of course, $\;F'(x)\;$ , and $\;F'(x)=\log x\;$ because this is the meaning of **primitive function** ... and I've no idea what "part 1, part 2"  you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\ln(x)$ is a continuous function in the open interval $(0,+\infty)$, from the Fundamental Theorem $g(x)=\int_a^x ln(t) dt$ (for any $a>0$) is differentiable in $(0,+\infty)$ and its derivative in this interval is $g'(x)=ln(x)$.